# PHP convert date format from xml feed from 25 November 2011 to 25 Nov?

Tags: php

Im importing content from an XML feed. The date format for the date field is 25 November 2011, which I need to convert into 25 Nov. Whats the best way to do this?

I could use str_replace to replace each month with its abbreviation, but im wondering if there is a cleaner solution.

Comment: So, so many duplicates... Many of them in the "related" column

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most elegant solution would be to use [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php).

```
$date = new DateTime("25 November 2011");
echo $date->format("j M");
```

Answer (score 0):

The quick/dirty version:

```
echo date('j M', strtotime('25 November 2011'));
```

if the input dates are potentially ambiguous (e.g. '1/2/3'), then use [`date_create_from_format()`](http://php.net/date_create_from_format) (or its OOP equivalent) instead.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted? Using the `DateTime` library is nicer, but this isn't *incorrect*

Comment: I wasn't the one who downvoted it, but I suspect the person who did did so because of the use of strtotime. Using stringtotime makes an unnecessary string step between the original and resulting representations.

Comment: @Frozen There are reasons to criticize strtotime, but that isn't one of them IMO. So what if a variable is produced? What's the harm?

Comment: The accepted solution is totally equivalent to strtotime as well, since it's using autoparse. But either way, no biggie.

Comment: @Frozenfire: datetime will STILL parse the date into an integer internally, and the re-convert back to string representation. In a strict efficient sense, the code is the basically the same size, and internally datetime is even less efficient as there's object overhead to deal with.

Comment: i'd rather suspect the dv to be due a 60k+ user repwhoring on an obvious duplicate

Answer (score 0):

```
 $newdate = date("d M", strtotime("25 November 2011"));

 echo $newdate;
```